# Tabs fazendo o dropdown fechar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap

Alguém consegue me ajudar, coloquei as tabs dentro de um dropdown e quando mudo de tab o dropdown fecha.

Login 
      
      
        
          
          
            
              Login Novo
              Login Antigo

```
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="novo">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="usuario@apelido" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-haspopup="true">Acessar</button>
            <p><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;<a href="#">Esqueci minha senha</a></p>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="antigo">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Código do Cliente" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-haspopup="true">Acessar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Descreva um pouco mais sobre o seu codigo, posta o CSS e o JS que complementa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvido com o código javascript

```
$('.dropdown-menu a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    $(this).tab('show')
})
```